# (ConditionA or ConditionB) and (ConditionB or ConditionA) behaving differently

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I was doing a small algorithmic problem. There are two arrays, arr1 and arr2. arr1 contains some random integers and arr2 contains integers which contains indexes of arr1 randomly. I was able to solve the problem, but in between, I got an error which is the central theme of this question. So, I will not go into details about explaining the original problem, but try to explain that using a different example.

Suppose I have two arrays:

```
arr1 = [1]
arr2 = []
```

If I use `print((arr1[arr2[-1]] < arr1[0]) or (not arr2))`, I will get an `IndexError` as `arr2` is empty, and calling `arr2[-1]` will cause this error.

But, if I use `print((not arr2) or (arr1[arr2[-1]] < arr1[0]))`, I am getting output as `True`. Well, this is what I actually wanted, but I am not able to figure out how swapping the conditions around `or` operator changed the output?

Comment: `or`, `and` shortcircuits. As in if first condition in `or` evaluates to Truthy, it won't check the other. And if the first condition is Falsey for `and` it won't check the others

Comment: `and` and `or` are always behaving smart. If the first condition is false (in `and`) or true (in `or`) the result is known so the second condition will never be **evaluated** and calculated.

Comment: @hansolo, so, does that mean if there are multiple "or" statements, wherever it gets true, it stops further evaluation, and returns True? And this happens left to right?

Comment: Yes, and the same for `and` if it gets `false`.

Comment: Yes, and yes. Evaluation happens from left to right in this case

Comment: @hansolo Okay, got it. Thanks!

Comment: @sgalpha To be precise, it doesn't return `True`. It returns the first value that evaluates to `True`. Test it with `print(None or "Hello" or True)`. If you use `and` it returns the last value the evaluates to `True`. Test: `print(True and [1])`